# Power BI How to filter and change time data rows

Tags: excel, powerbi, export

Last week I exported table from internal system to Power BI (About 20,000 rows). The table contains a list of entered work inputs ( What the worker did recorded at the time ). Most workers have similar inputs, i.e. entry ( Prichod ), start of work ( JOBID ) and departure from the site ( Odchod ).

https://postimg.cc/Xp4z2h5L

The workers can also working on parallel works ( Green ), where the records have the same time and the end of the work. The only difference is the time of work ( Together they make the time difference between the start and end of work ) and the parallel parameter. However, the second system is not able to import data like this and process these inputs as duplicates.

I would like to recalculate the parallel rows time according to TimeOfWork, but I am not able to create the condition and filter correctly. Could someone help me?

Rows should be edited like this ( Orange )

https://postimg.cc/FdmhDpVL

Data have to be in Power Bi and I can't edit the inputs or outputs from the systems. There can be more than 2 parallel jobs as one record.

Thanks.

I tried DAX function like EARLIER but was not able to filter the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Did this in DAX ( Created new index in Power Query ) and add new column which separates data to groups and sum TimeOfJob.

```
TimeOfWork = 

enter code here`var CurrentDate = 'Time registration'[CorrectedStartDate]
var Employee = 'Time registration'[WorkerPersonnelNumber]
var CurrentRow = 'Time registration'[Index]
var WorkParalel = 'Time registration'[TimeAllocationType]
var StartTime = 'Time registration'[CorrectedStartTime_T]

var NewFilteredTable = FILTER('Time registration',
'Time registration'[WorkerPersonnelNumber] = Employee &&
'Time registration'[CorrectedStartDate] = CurrentDate &&
'Time registration'[CorrectedStartTime_T] = StartTime &&
'Time registration'[TimeAllocationType] = "Bundle1")

return (CALCULATE(SUM('Time registration'[CorrectedTimeOfJob]), FILTER(NewFilteredTable,'Time registration'[Index]<=CurrentRow)))
```

I Created new calculation column CadEndDate where I am using:

```
CaEndDate = StartDate + TimeStart + TimeOfWork
```

Then I created second column CaStartDate where I wrote:

```
CaStartDate = CalculatedEndDate - TimeOfWork
```

Thanks for helping me.